# How to directly Send User to HomePage after SignIn (Signup) is successful

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is my Code

```
RoundedElevatedButton(
  child: const Text("Sign in"),
  onPress: () async {
    try {
      await   FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.runtimeType);
    }
  });
```

I want To send the user to the homepage directly after login succeeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the onPress function as follows:

```dart
 onPress: () async {
          try {
            final user = await   FirebaseAuth.instance
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            
            if(user!=null){
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home'); //Navigate to home screen.
            }

          } catch (e) {
            print(e.runtimeType);
          }
        }
```